# Uncaught exception 'Zend_Log_Exception' with message file.log cannot be opened with mode "a"

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm facing the following error:

> Uncaught exception 'Zend_Log_Exception' with message  file.log cannot be opened with mode "a"

In my bootstrap I have the following code:

```
$logfile = PROJECT_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .'/tmp/logs/'.$config->app->logfile.'.log';

if (!file_exists($logfile))
{
  $fp = fopen($logfile, 'a');
  fclose($fp);
}

$redacteur = new Zend_Log_Writer_Stream($logfile);
$logger    = new Zend_Log($redacteur);
```

The full error page:

> Warning:
>   fopen(/home/http/me.tv/fbapps/www//tmp/logs/vengeance.log)
>   [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/http/me.tv/fbapps/www/inline/bootstrap_vengeance.php on
>   line 81
>
> Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in
>   /home/http/me.tv/fbapps/www/inline/bootstrap_vengeance.php on
>   line 82
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Log_Exception' with message
>   '"/home/http/me.tv/fbapps/www//tmp/logs/vengeance.log" cannot
>   be opened with mode "a"' in
>   /home/http/me.tv/fbapps/www/library/Zend/Log/Writer/Stream.php:78
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /home/http/me.tv/fbapps/www/inline/bootstrap_vengeance.php(85):
>   Zend_Log_Writer_Stream->__construct('/home/http/medi...') #1
>   /home/http/me.tv/fbapps/www/htdocs/vengeance/index.php(9):
>   require_once('/home/http/medi...') #2 {main} thrown in
>   /home/http/me.tv/fbapps/www/library/Zend/Log/Writer/Stream.php
>   on line 78

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Put the right permission on the file: `0777`.

Check if the directory `/home/http/me.tv/fbapps/www/tmp/logs/` exists, then run this command in a terminal:

```
chmod 777 /home/http/me.tv/fbapps/www/tmp/logs/vengeance.log
```

Comment: I had permissions '755' on the whole directory and the file didn't exist. Changing permissions on the directory to '777' solved the issue.

Comment: I've put chmod 777 on both the file AND the directory.. PHPUnit is sitll giving me the same error message. `cannot be opened in mode "a" `

Comment: this is not much of a solution if you create log file based on dates

Comment: Solving an issue by introduting a security breach is not an acceptable solution. Just give the right right to the right user.

Answer (score 2):

The web server user should have the right to write and exec (to pass through) on the logs folder.

`chown www-data:www-data -R logs/ # change www-data by the user of the web server
chmod 755 -R logs/`

It s a very bad idea to put 777 somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Like Clem said, you should not give a log file 777 access. It is wrong and introduces vulnerabilities to your app. Another way to give access to your file is giving access like this:

`chmod u=rw,g=rw,o=rw file.log`

If you want to give read and write access only to specific user/groups make sure you remove the `o=rw` and add the proper owner/group

`chown user:group file.log`